# Create NumberPad in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a `TextField` with a numeric keyboard type. My code right now looks like this:

```swift
TextField("Placeholder", text: self.$text)
```

I am looking for something like this:

[image: Text Field with number pad]

Comment: Deleted previous comment due to poor proof-reading. This question is perfectly reasonable in the context of Apple's new `SwiftUI` framework. It's pretty clear what the OP is asking. I personally don't know the answer (yet), but it's a good question.

Comment: I've had the same question. I haven't tried it by my thought was to use `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap `TextField`.

Comment: Why would this question be closed? it's a good question, it's not broad at all, and I do want to know the answer too!